# Converting signed to unsigned in Swift

Tags: types, swift, operands

In C, I am able to do a trick with numbers:

```
uint8_t value = 0
int delta = -1
uint8_t result = value + delta  /* result will be 0xFF */
```

Is there a way of doing the same in Swift? Notice that the same approach doesn't work:

```
let value: UInt8 = 0
let delta: Int = -1
var result: UInt8 = value + delta  // Error, even typecasting in different ways...
```

Is there a way to get C's behaviour for substraction in Swift?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All signed and unsigned integer types have a `bitPattern:` constructor,
which creates an unsigned number from a signed (or vice versa) with the same
memory representation:

```
let delta: Int8 = -1
let result: UInt8 = UInt8(bitPattern: delta) // 0xFF = 255
```

Comment: Only one correction is needed, I see: 'UInt8(bitPattern: Int8(delta))' is needed instead of simple 'UInt8(bitPattern: delta)' (or delta needs to be Int8).

Answer (score 6):

(I think your example is a little off. `0 - -1` is 1. I believe this answer is what you were thinking of, though).

You want to opt-into overflow with the `&-` operator:

```
let value: UInt8 = 0
let delta: UInt8 = 1
let result: UInt8 = value &- delta
```

There are similar things you can do with the other `&` operators like `&+`, `&*`, etc. There's even a `&/` that handles divide by zero.

Comment: Oh! Sorry... The code was wrong (typing too fast...). It is corrected now.

Comment: With the corrected sample code, the other answer works better, but this is useful information anyway. Thanks!