# How to convert the byte data of Int32 to UInt32 and back?

Tags: swift, int, byte, uint

**Academically Natured Question:**
How can the byte data of an Int32 with the value of -1 be cast into an UInt32? *(can SWIFT do that?)*

**Understanding:**
I know that -1 isn't a value that can be represented by an Unsigned Integer, as UInts only contain Integers above -1

However I also know that both Int32 and UInt32 take the same amount of space in Bytes *(4*8=32)*.
 That byte space should be able to be used for either type, regardless if it represents the same value... which it obviously wouldn't.

**Conclusion:**
There should be some simple way to take the raw bit data of an Int32 and use it for a UInt32...

Comment: What have you tried?  Why is this a Swift/Objective-C question (unless you show code, this is a general numerical question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the variable via bitPattern (thanks Jthora). Plenty of help here on SO for this:

- [Converting signed to unsigned in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666846/converting-signed-to-unsigned-in-swift)
- [Int to UInt (and vice versa) bit casting in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127124/int-to-uint-and-vice-versa-bit-casting-in-swift)

For 32-bits, 0xffffffff=> -1 when signed or 4294967295 unsigned.

Comment: The answer is casting Int32 as UInt32 using the bitPattern: method! _(did not know about bitPattern: method)_ Edit your answer to include the bitPattern thing and I'll green check ya!