# Unsigned Int to negative Int in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, int, unsigned

I'm working with the Pebble accelerometer data and need to convert the unsigned representations of negative ints to normal numbers (note the first two for example).

`[X: 4294967241, Z: 4294967202, Y: 22]
    [X: 4294967278, Z: 4294967270, Y: 46]
    [X: 4294967274, Z: 4294967278, Y: 26]
    [X: 4294967221, Z: 85, Y: 4294967280]
    [X: 4294967247, Z: 117, Y: 4294967266]`

Using Objective C I've managed to do so by the simple `[number intValue]`. However, using Swift I can't find a way to do so. I've tried `Int(number)`, but I get the same value.

Comment: Am I reading unsigned negative int right? You can also just use abs to get an Int's absolute value.

Comment: An unsigned negative number doesn't exist, do you mean negative signed maybe?

Comment: Can you add more examples of values your getting? Also what's the type of those values? UInt32? Int32? Int16?

Comment: @Kametrixom unsigned representation of a negative number. I've updated the post with more values.

Comment: And what's the type of the X and Y values??

Comment: @Kametrixom string, but I was only trying to convert the numbers. Anyway, your code worked :)

Comment: Wow, really weird that you only have a string, something must have gone wrong somewhere. Btw if my answer is really working for you, you can accept it ;)

Comment: Compare [Converting signed to unsigned in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666846/converting-signed-to-unsigned-in-swift) (which is essentially the same problem, only into the opposite direction).

Comment: It would also be interesting to know *how* you retrieve those values. I would imagine that this can be fixed earlier.

Answer (score 5):

You can always do an `unsafeBitcast` if you received the wrong type:

```
unsafeBitCast(UInt32(4294967009), Int32.self)  // -287
```

This for example converts an `UInt32` to an `Int32`

EDIT: [vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630618/vacawama) showed a better solution without the nasty `unsafe`:

```
Int32(bitPattern: 4294967009)
```

Thanks a lot! Use this one instead, it's safe (obviously) and probably faster

Comment: Can also be done with `Int32(bitPattern: 4294967009)` which doesn't have that nasty `unsafe` word in it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `bitPattern` in the constructor to convert unsigned to signed:

```
let x = Int32(bitPattern: 4294967009)
print(x)  // prints "-287"
```

or if your value is already stored in a variable:

```
let x: UInt32 = 4294967241
let y = Int32(bitPattern: x)
print(y)  // prints "-55"
```

If your value is stored as a 64-bit `UInt`, you need to use `truncatingBitPattern` when converting to `Int32`:

```
let x: UInt = 4294967241
let y = Int(Int32(truncatingBitPattern: x))
print(y)  // prints "-55"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to convert an unsigned representation of a negative number into it's signed representation? If so, this should work:

```
let negativeValue = Int((incomingValue - 0xffffffff) % 0xffffffff)
```

Comment: `%` has a higher precendence than `-`, I think you need some brackets

Comment: That's not working, it just turns all my values into negative.

Comment: @MartiSerraVivancos Maybe the values ARE negative??

Comment: @Kametrixom not all of them are. The code is turning positive numbers into negative and unsigned representations of negative into large negative ints. Like this: [X: -4294967009, Z: -4294967262, Y: -112]